# Xcode6, iOS8 and (void)layoutSubviews

Tags: uilabel, autolayout, ios8, xcode6, layoutsubviews

I have custom UILabel which works fine on iOS6 and iOS7. But on iOS8 this label's (void)layoutSubviews method never get called. 
I create this label with initWithFrame, so this method should be called - and it's called on another iOS versions.
What happens with autoLayout system in iOS8?

Comment: The issue is even worse, as also when using autolayout for the subview, it does not get layoutet.

Comment: I created an example project showing the issue. Run on iOS 7 and 8 to see the difference. https://github.com/fabb/LabelTest

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you get any answer on this?

Comment: Seems issue has been fixed in iOS 8.1 beta version.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add this answer because the question title may lead a lot of ppl here with similar issues (like me).

With iOS 8 to 8.0.2 `LayoutSubviews` calls are unreliable. They may not be called ever or (in my case) are called in a loop.

Even though you should not do it, it was pretty safe to alloc stuff in LayoutSubviews, but with this buggy (?!) behaviour it can cause hard-to-trace bugs.

I don't know if 8.1 fixes all the issues but it will be some time until customer devices will run 8.1 and they do run 8.0.2 NOW

Comment: Am facing the same issue here. "LayoutSubviews" is called in a loop
In order to cover users using iOS 8.0.2, Is there any Fix for this bug?

Comment: no, to my knowledge there is no fix. But you should not try to support versions of iOS that were in-between-versions. If someone still uses 8.0 or 8.0.2 they can upgrade to a newer version and fix the problem themselves.

Comment: Yeah that's true. But, unfortunately in apps, we can't ask every customer stucked on that version to upgrade their device. ;)
Well, i think i have found a way around. Thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. Really layoutSubviews is not called anymore for UILabel on iOS8, as Apple does not expect anybody uses it as superview.

I am using [ReactiveCocoaLayout](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoaLayout), so it can be done by subscribing to rcl_frameSignal or rcl_boundsSignal.

`-(void)awakeFromNib
{
   [ self.rcl_boundsSignal 
    subscribeNext:
    ^( NSValue* boundsValue )
    {
       //layout changed
    } ];
}`

Or you can use simple KVO to know when frame has been changed:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
   [ self removeObserver: self forKeyPath: @"layer.bounds" ];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:( NSString* )keyPath
                     ofObject:( id )object
                       change:( NSDictionary* )change
                      context:( void* )context
{
   if ( [ keyPath isEqualToString: @"layer.bounds" ] )
   {
      //layoutSubviews
   }
   else
   {
      [ super observeValueForKeyPath: keyPath
                      ofObject: object
                        change: change
                       context: context ];
   }
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
   [ self addObserver: self
           forKeyPath: @"layer.bounds"
              options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context: 0 ];
}
```

Comment: Note that UIKit is per documentation **NOT** KVO-compliant - even if it works for some cases, it might break in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The bug was fixed by Apple in iOS 8.1 (beta).

Comment: do you have a link or something to back that up ?

Comment: Can confirm, layoutSubview gets called again in 8.1 beta

Comment: I have filed a Radar with Apple. And I have created a sample project: github.com/fabb/LabelTest